# Filter results with custom field values and dropdown

Tags: custom-field, customization, filters, search, dropdown

I need to filter posts by a custom field value.

My specific example:

- User browse to products > category 1 > subcategory A.
- ALL "subcategory A" items (products custom post type) are displayed
  as default by date.
- Each item in subcategory A has a custom field "size". User can select the size with a dropdown menu and posts are filtered displaying only items with "custom field:size" = "selected size". Filter is kept also in pagination, because products are on more pages.

I've checked a lot of answers, but no case was simple as that. I was thinking about doing it using a custom search or a plugin, but I really don't know where to start. thanks for your help.

EDIT: the custom field values are fixed, not auto-populated. The select can be built in plain html without extra queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited according to first comments** and Pastebin code:

```
<?php /* You can also leave 'action' blank: action="" */ ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name="my_size" id="size" class="postform" onchange="submit();">
        <option selected="selected">Choose a size</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
</form>
<?php /* Reset filter */ ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Clear filter</a></p>

<?php
if( !isset($_POST['my_size']) || '' == $_POST['my_size']) {

    // unfiltered product list here

}
else {

    // Get dropdown value
    // Don't forget to sanitize this!
    $size = $_POST['my_size'];

    // Create new query
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'=> 'product', // your CPT
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'size',
        'meta_value' => $size, // Dropdown value
    ) );

    // Loop
    if($query->have_posts()):
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            // Product content
        endwhile;
    endif;

    // reset query to default
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

See Codex for [WP_Query reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Thanks Max. I tried your solution but I'm stuck with the submit of the select, this is the code I used http://pastebin.com/t36UWQsP I don't know which "action" is correct for the form submitting on "self". If I understood it should append "&my_size=xx" at the end of url as a parameter, right? Your solution looks right, but my php knowledge is pretty basic, sorry.

Comment: Andycap, please see amended code above.

Comment: Andycap, you are welcome. I forgot to answer your question about URL parameters. When you use `method="get"`, parameters are appended, when `method="post"` you don't see them in URL.

Comment: Max, thanks for that instructive detail, I had already figured it out reading a tutorial on php GET and POST.

Comment: I don't understand what happens but it's showing posts with "Size" and lower (i.e. size=10, it's showing 10,9,8, etc..). I also tried with 'compare' => '=' but nothing.

Comment: Andycap, try to cast `$size` like this:    
`$size = (int) $_POST['my_size'];`

Comment: Every selection is behaving different, but seems I got what's the problem. The number it returns it's in the post title! I.e. if i select 18 (no posts with size=18) it returns 2 posts that have "18" in the title. I think the problem is in the wp_query.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't replicate this problem. Everything works fine for me even without $size` type casting. May be paste your whole page where you run this query to Pastebin.

Comment: Here's the products page (where the wp_query is)http://pastebin.com/X4NdSzp0 and this is the loop that displays the products http://pastebin.com/KPAMWWjY 
I'm using a theme, so the code is pretty long. "pollici" is the custom field that I need to filter with "my_size"

Comment: As I understood, you've made a mess with `WP_Query` parameters. See fixed page: http://pastebin.com/SbHwvw9G

Comment: Thanks Max, your solution was working perfectly. It was my fault, the theme add a suffix to the custom field so I was putting the wrong meta_key. Thanks for your time